# Нужна ли ещё одна запятая после одиночного деепричастия?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Надо ли ставить запятую перед союзом "и" после одиночного деепричастия "оценив"?

*Андрей поворчал немного, оценив, надо ли было тратить столько денег(,) и сказал:*

Comment: Это не оборот, а односоставное с сказуемым ‟надо было тратить”. Не обязательно должно быть главное, почти все определительные придаточные, например, относятся только к одному слову или сочетанию.

Comment: Точнее, главное должно быть, но придаточное может относится только к одному слову из главного.

Comment: @slava1947 да, вы правы, я сглупил. Исправил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Андрей поворчал немного, оценив, надо ли было тратить столько денег, и сказал...**

[UPD: пояснение исправлено]

*Андрей поворчал немного, оценив* (главная часть), *надо ли было тратить столько денег* (придаточное изъяснительное), *и сказал...*